# Drop Caps, but Capitalize First Letter with CSS

Tags: css

The database provides all caps for the title of products.  They need to transformed to lower case, except the first letter.

What's a pure CSS approach that can work with IE8+, Safari 5+ (IE7 optional)?

Legacy code of my system:

```
<ul>
    <li class="cart-column column-seventy">
    <h4><a href="">THIS IS THE TITLE OF AN OBJECT</a></h4>
   </li>
</ul>
```

- **Original:** THIS IS THE TITLE OF AN OBJECT
- **Desired CSS changes**  This is the title of an object

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```css
.TextToFix {
    text-transform:lowercase;
}

.TextToFix:first-letter {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="TextToFix">MY PRODUCT</div>
```

Should work back to IE 5.5.

Comment: @JuanMendes - thanks for the code snippet.

Comment: Good answer. The :first-letter tag is supported as far back as IE6.